# Were there any ancient civilisation that functioned without currency or bartering?

Tags: economy, law, currency, civilizations, cities

As required here is how I define the terms used in this question:

• money/currency: is something that has little use to the individuals (such as metal coins) but has a commonly recognized value the society that allows individuals to exchange it for any services or goods
• barter: is not money, is not a service, is a good that can be exchanged against any other good freely by individuals who agree to
• civilisation/city state: is a society whose development requires distinct skillsets (warrior, administrator, carpenter, miner, nurse, teacher, etc)

I'd like to know if any civilisation has managed to develop an economic system where all the tasks/jobs to run the society/country were done and all the people received what they needed to live and accomplish their tasks, without money or barter.
I'd like to know how such civilisation ensured that there was enough of each worker/skillset, enough of production, and how it prevented people to work too little or ask too much.

Comment: `without the use of money or barter` Why do you think they did it without the use of bartering? I think bartering predated civilisation.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: @Semaphore I think bartering is not handy at all on a daily basis for individuals. It must have been used by merchants only who then found money to be more handy and that's how the use of currency began. Bartering is also unnecessary when the laws ensure a balanced economy.

Comment: There are a number of questionable assumptions; 1) "traditional tribes have laws", 2) "Everybody works", 3) "everybody gets what they need".  4)  humans exist without barter.  "traditional tribes" have nothing to do with city states.  Every society prior to the modern era has been comfortable with the notion of poverty and starvation.

Comment: @WaterBearer You're right that bartering is not handy; that's why they invented currency. However, there is no reason to assume bartering was only limited to merchants. Even non-merchants today barter; for example children trading food at lunch time. I'm not sure what you mean by "laws ensure a balanced economy", but before currency, no economy balanced or otherwise could exist without bartering, because some mechanism was always needed for trade beyond a familial scale.

Comment: @Semaphore that's the point of my question, with adequate laws it must be possible that all those who works for the society get from it what they need to live in it. They don't earn money they earn the right, this is the mechanism. This is how tribes function to this day, all men go hunting to bring food, all women stay home to raise kids and make art items, and all eat at the end of the day, yet no barter or money was involved, only laws common to several families.

Comment: So you're asking if proto-communism existed in ancient civilisations?

Comment: @Semaphore if you want to call it like that yes.

Comment: @WaterBearer Well, this is very disingenuous. You're not interested in how things actually worked, but rather pushing for answers that present a version of history as you imagined.

Comment: @WaterBearer _This is how tribes function to this day, all men go hunting to bring food, all women stay home to raise kids and make art items, and all eat at the end of the day,_ Really? Which tribes? I had the good fortune to spend a month with a Sen Bushman family in Botswana in the 1970s, and I really don't recognise that description.

Comment: @sempaiscuba I don't have names, I just recall from the many documentaries I saw. Feel free to post an answer to explain how tribes are ran by barter instead of laws and duties.

Comment: @WaterBearer Again, I'd encourage you to to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask]. Questions about modern ethnography are off-topic. As it stands, I suspect your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: 1) I suggest you define barter 2) read David Greaber "Debt: The first 5000 years", he critizises the idea that an ancient societies ran on barter the way Adam Smith later described it - been years since I've read it, so I can't write an answer on that basis 3) this might also be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palace_economy

Comment: This question shows no foundation in actual history.

Comment: Without currency, money and barter defined or at least differentiated this remains difficult to even understand properly. Money and currency are quite different and late inventions as is barter. Any answer might benefit from following @mart 's lead. But without clarification in the question, also how "laws" come into play, this will be a tedious chore. Any books, articles to illustrate your current understanding, perhaps instead of doc/movies and hearsay?

Comment: Latest edit does improve things. But apart from your own definitions, what is your literary (including documentaries) base for this reasoning (we are all standing on the shoulders of giants…) [Previously you wrote "we all know": where did this come from?]

Comment: @LangLangC that's an assumption I made based on the many documentaries I saw on prebarter tribes.

Comment: This is an interesting question, so I don't see why either the downvotes or the closing. But people are right that there are problems with the definitions - though I would say the main problem isn't the definition of currency or of barter, but rather that of "civilisation". And perhaps that of "economy", but that is a wormier can of worms.

Comment: No society that I am informed ever based its "economy" on barter. The distribution of goods and services, where there is no market, or were the market is ancillary, is either a free distribution of what is produced - as among hunter-gatherers - or based on top-down decisions, as it was the case for much, or most, of production in "tributary" or "feudal" societies.

Comment: Barter was usually a inter-societary issue, with tribes exchanging their excedents collectively, not a way to distribute goods internally. As for currency, your definition is good and valid for a somewhat developed circulation system; but early, rudimentary, forms of currency, depended on *useful* commodities - frequently cattle. That is no longer bartering, as there is one, or a few, commodities that are used as means of payment, but is still one step away from proper currency, which is what you define as "something that has little use to the individuals but has a commonly recognized value".

Comment: The greater problem, however, is the definition of civilisation. Your definition is unusual; the most common definitions rely on the existence of a centralised State, urban settlements, and/or a writing system. But those definitions are to some degree arbitrary - to the point that you could actually define "civilisation" as "a society that has metallic currency" - and so answer your question *a priori*.

Comment: More to the point, barter was never systematical within any society; it is rather an issue of "foreign relations" or a complement to proper market relations. Before industrialisation, while currency has existed for a long time, the biggest share of production either remained at the hands of their direct producers, or was extracted via non-market devices (taxes and rents in product or in labour).

Answer (score 2):

(I do not know if this is an answer but having read OP's profile, he seems to be trying to get with the *program* of SE, so I will try to help.)

---

First, the answer to this is more convoluted than it seems at first sight. Hence, it does require more elaboration from OP, such as narrowing the question, or at least establishing some terms of reference in the question.

Second, unless one is well-versed in not just history, but also economic theory and jurisprudence, the answer will most likely be unsatisfactory.

Allow me to illustrate with a few points:

- concept of currency
- concept of barter
- private property

---

**Concept of Currency**

- In **[Wealth of Nations](https://www.adamsmith.org/the-wealth-of-nations/)**, Adam Smith used **corn**, **silk** and other commodities as reference for currency because (and this is where it gets tricky), he was trying to show the nominal value of goods (think *inflation*), regardless of effort (labour) required. In his chapter on ***Division of Labour, paragrph 4***:

> In agriculture, the labour of the rich country is not always much more productive than that of the poor; or, at least, it is never so much more productive as it commonly is in manufactures. ***The corn of the rich country, therefore, will not always, in the same degree of goodness, come cheaper to market than that of the poor.*** The corn of Poland, in the same degree of goodness, is as cheap as that of France, notwithstanding the superior opulence and improvement of the latter country. The corn of France is, in the corn provinces, fully as good, and in most years nearly about the same price with the corn of England, though, in opulence and improvement, France is perhaps inferior to England. The corn-lands of England, however, are better cultivated than those of France, and the corn-lands of France are said to be much better cultivated than those of Poland. But though the poor country, notwithstanding the inferiority of its cultivation, can, in some measure, rival the rich in the cheapness and goodness of its corn, it can pretend to no such competition in its manufactures; at least if those manufactures suit the soil, climate, and situation of the rich country. ***The silks of France are better and cheaper than those of England, because the silk manufacture, at least under the present high duties upon the importation of raw silk, does not so well suit the climate of England as that of France.*** But the hardware and the coarse woollens of England are beyond all comparison superior to those of France, and much cheaper too in the same degree of goodness. In Poland there are said to be scarce any manufactures of any kind, a few of those coarser household manufactures excepted, without which no country can well subsist.

What I believe OP is looking for, is not really definitions of **[fiat currency/money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat_money)**, but understanding how societies functioned before the invention of fiat money. Hence, the alternate **system of barter** in the question title.

---

**Concept of Barter**

In the context of this question, bartering is seen as an accepted form of exchange for goods and services without the use of fiat money. To this end, it is a natural choice if money was not available (not yet invented, for instance). Unfortunately, on a deeper level of analysis, this is not true.

> *The mainstream economists' view that barter should be seen as a `natural' phenomenon of human nature and as the origin of money is rejected*. ***Barter occurs in specific socio-economic conditions which may obtain also in economies which know money. When there is a very low supply of currency, money may cease to function as an index of value for all goods and itself become an item bartered.*** This is likely to occur when small discrete social groups wish to maintain autonomy. Unlike money payment, which requires a further transaction before value is realised, barter satisfies demand immediately and is of its nature discontinuous. As with car trade-ins in our economy barter occurs when people cannot afford to keep money, and it becomes a system when society is atomised to the extent that people do not exploit the variations in exchange ratios between different communities. Using the case of the Lhomi of north-east Nepal, it is shown that althoug the exchange of common produce, as opposed to rare valuables, is most likely to approximate to a notional 'equilibrium price', the practice of barter with no established measures of weight and volume means that there can be no underlying index of value/numeraire. Each transaction exists virtually on its own. Thus, although barter is an egalitarian mode, it contains no protection against changing exchange ratios which may harm one partner. Barter tends to take place between people who know one another, because it is only by the establishment of customary times and places for exchange that the costs of searching for partners, waiting etc. are avoided. Delayed barter, which often occurs with valuables, requires non-economic means of ensuring repayment, but the ritualised trade-partnerships which the Lhomi employ are self-limiting: restricted relations cut traders off from the wide, unpredictable world of the capitalist end sale. Business often fails and the traders suffer.

Source: Caroline Humphrey, **[Barter and Economic Disintegration](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2802221?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)**, Man, New Series, Vol. 20, No. 1 (Mar., 1985), pp. 48-72, Royal Anthropological Institute of Great Britain and Ireland.

---

**Private Property**

Again, back to OP's intent in the question, I believe what OP meant to research on is not just how societies functioned without fiat money, but also how they were compensated (e.g. for their effort). This begs the next question, what if these societies did not understand (hence, did not practice) the concept of private property?

In economic history, private property is considered **[crucial to the development of modern economic society](https://fee.org/articles/talk-about-a-revolution/)** (and the Industrial Revolution). Conveniently, we can point to **[John Locke (1634 - 1704)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/locke/)**, as the one who helped us (modern society) identify the **[value of private property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Locke#Theory_of_value_and_property)**. So, how did the Romans, Assyrians, Mongols - (name your tribal culture) - get paid before Locke? Now we get into legal theory, **what is private property**?

---

What I hope to show, especially to OP (and anyone new to History SE), is the need for clarity in a question. In this sense, the somewhat strict requirements when posting questions is utilitarian, not an arbitrary after-thought.

Let me end by saying, I am well aware this post does not *answer* OP's question. What I hope to show is, the question itself is unanswerable in its current form (well, for me anyways). Much more thought and revision is required.

Comment: Should I make this a _community wiki_? Will it help?

Comment: Appreciate your reasoning on answering somewhat. I think you should wait until the OP clarifies his Q. / As it stands, your A is much too modern in its concepts and time frames to address the "ancient" part. If you want to address the Q *now*, and: still, this would need a much broader approach, doing all the def part the OP misses, for ancient societies ("civiliasations" )which will make this A likely a bit long.

Comment: @LangLangC - Yep, it's too modern, not sufficiently ancient -- that was _my problem_ when I first thought about this question.

Answer (score -1):

That's not possible. One uses money, barters or do a bit of both. [Corvée](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corv%C3%A9e), duties one has to do in order to fulfill obligations or gain benefits are a form of barter.

As far as I know, no society gives anyone what they want without the use of money or barter. Resources are always limited, and what one wants or feel they absolutely need cannot be met indefinitely.

Comment: I disagree, duties cannot be barters, duties are laws. With that definition we can see that all tribes use duty and not barter to function. Barter imply that there is no law and anything can be exchanged.

Comment: @WaterBearer `With that definition we can see that all tribes use duty and not barter to function.`  Based on this and your earlier comment, it seems you're not talking about tribes on the planet Earth. Currency existed in many tribes, and bartering in the rest.

Comment: @Semaphore well feel free to explain in an answer the different models and how what I assume is impossible.

Comment: This answer states a lot of claims without any evidence.

Comment: @BenCrowell I beg to differ. what exactly do I claim without evidence? There is bartering and money. I haven't heard about alternatives. I'm all ears. If there is, what is it?

Comment: @WaterBearer: you need to clarify what exactly you mean. Bartering is a form of negotiating. Laws are different. Besides, primitive tribes don't have laws. They have rules they live by. If you think alternatives beyond money and bartering exist, tell us.

Comment: @Jos it's what I think, I can't imagine otherwise but I admit I have not studied the matter. In tribes (any I can think of especially in the jungle) the men go hunt meat or raise cattle while the women make clothes, basketry and work the field/gather fruits. At the end of the day food is shared among all members of the tribe. Where is money ? where is barter ? Similarly when a house needs to be built or restored, all men of the tribe participate.

Comment: @WaterBearer That's a division of labor. Those tribes haven't progressed to the bartering stage yet. After bartering comes money. That's another step.

Comment: "no society gives anyone what they want without the use of money or barter." - no, but you can grow/fetch/build it yourself and then you have it without involving any money or barter. Or (in small groups of people) everyone grows/fetches/builds stuff for everyone and those who don't pull their weight get kicked out.